# Switch case inside a range slider javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to make a range slider in which if i am selecting one value with the slider - it will display one thing, if i am selecting another value- it will display another thing. So i am trying to do it with a switch case: if you are on value 0- then show me this message, if you are on value 30 - show me another message. The problem is that it doesnt work at all….Here i added my code:

!(https://postimg.cc/Lnd1PhSs)

So my HTML code is like this:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
};

switch (output) {
  case 0:
    document.write("Good job<br />");
    break;

  case 30:
    document.write("Pretty good<br />");
    break;

  case 60:
    document.write("Passed<br />");
    break;

  case 90:
    document.write("Passed<br />");
    break;
  default:
    document.write("Unknown grade<br />");
}

document.write("Exiting switch block");
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: grey;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(58, 111, 46);
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(58, 111, 46);
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="90" value="0" step="30" class="slider" id="myRange">
<p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

Comment: First, you should not be using document.write, second output is an DOM element and you are comparing it to a number. Third that switch is only called one time when it loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply an working event to the element and hand over `this`. Then you could take the value and convert it to a number, because all results of an input in HTML is a  string and needs a conversion, if requested. `switch` uses strict comparion, and if you take a string and comare the value with a number, you get always `false`.

Then you need to take the text. The best was is to take another element of the page and show the result there. `document.write` works only if the page has not rendered to the end and is not advisable to use.

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result"),
    output = document.getElementById("demo");

function update(element) {
    var value = +element.value, // convert to number
        text;

    output.innerHTML = value;

    switch (value) {
        case 0:
            text = "Good job";
            break;
        case 30:
            text = "Pretty good";
            break;
        case 60:
            text = "Passed";
            break;
        case 90:
            text = "Passed";
            break;
        default:
           text = "Unknown grade";
    }
    result.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="90" value="0" step="30" class="slider" id="myRange" onchange="update(this)">
<p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The switch block is outside of your **oninput** callback function, so it won
't be evaluated if the value of the slider changes.
Furthermore, **document.write()** will replace your whole html document. Try **console.log()** instead.
Lastly, **this.value** is of type String - inside your switch block you're checking for integer values. Use **parseInt(this.value)** to convert the input to a number.

```js
  var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
  var output = document.getElementById("demo");
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;

  slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
    switch (parseInt(this.value)) {
      case 0:
        console.log("Good job<br />");
        break;

      case 30:
        console.log("Pretty good<br />");
        break;

      case 60:
        console.log("Passed<br />");
        break;

      case 90:
        console.log("Passed<br />");
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Unknown grade<br />");

    }

  };
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: grey;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(58, 111, 46);
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(58, 111, 46);
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="90" value="0" step="30" class="slider" id="myRange">
<p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your code with few `Javascript` fixes. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var message = document.getElementById("message");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  switch (parseInt(this.value)) {
  case 0:
    messageAppend("Good job");
    break;

  case 30:
    messageAppend("Pretty good");
    break;

  case 60:
    messageAppend("Passed");
    break;

  case 90:
    messageAppend("Passed");
    break;
    
  default:
    messageAppend("Unknown grade");
  }
};


function messageAppend(text) {
  message.innerText = text;
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: grey;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(58, 111, 46);
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(58, 111, 46);
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="90" value="0" step="30" class="slider" id="myRange">
<p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
<div id="message"></div>
```